# Device manager and Postgresql error message loop

Tags: osx-server, postgresql, serveradmin

I'm on MBP 7,1, 2.4GHz Intel Core 2 Duo, 4GB DDR3 Ram, 500GB hard drive with Lion. After the v10.7.3 update, the console has been putting a looping error message regarding Device manager and PostGre SQL (below). Can anyone help?

```
23/02/12 12:47:07.662 PM com.apple.launchd: (org.postgresql.postgres[1110]) Exited with code: 2
23/02/12 12:47:07.662 PM com.apple.launchd: (org.postgresql.postgres) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
23/02/12 12:47:13.834 PM com.apple.devicemanager: DEBUG: Initializing DeviceManagerDaemon with ports 3320,3321,3322,3323 (physmem = 4GB)
23/02/12 12:47:13.834 PM com.apple.devicemanager: DEBUG: Making sure Rails is configured properly
23/02/12 12:47:13.834 PM com.apple.devicemanager: DEBUG: Running rake command: /usr/bin/rake db:migrate
23/02/12 12:47:15.044 PM ruby: Unable to create ProfileManager log file at '/var/log/devicemgr/profilemanager.log' (No such file or directory)
23/02/12 12:47:15.044 PM ProfileManager: Unable to create ProfileManager log file at '/var/log/devicemgr/profilemanager.log' (No such file or directory)
23/02/12 12:47:15.045 PM com.apple.devicemanager: Feb 23 12:47:15 Computer.local ProfileManager[1116] <Error>: Unable to create ProfileManager log file at '/var/log/devicemgr/profilemanager.log' (No such file or directory)
23/02/12 12:47:16.449 PM com.apple.devicemanager: rake aborted!
23/02/12 12:47:16.449 PM com.apple.devicemanager: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
23/02/12 12:47:16.449 PM com.apple.devicemanager:           Is the server running locally and accepting
23/02/12 12:47:16.449 PM com.apple.devicemanager:           connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
23/02/12 12:47:16.450 PM com.apple.devicemanager: (See full trace by running task with --trace)
23/02/12 12:47:16.461 PM com.apple.devicemanager: (in /usr/share/devicemgr/backend)
23/02/12 12:47:16.470 PM com.apple.devicemanager: /usr/share/devicemgr/backend/devicemgrd:109:in `rake': Rake command failed with 256 (RuntimeError)
23/02/12 12:47:16.470 PM com.apple.devicemanager:           from /usr/share/devicemgr/backend/devicemgrd:103:in `setupRails'
23/02/12 12:47:16.470 PM com.apple.devicemanager:           from /usr/share/devicemgr/backend/devicemgrd:33:in `run'
23/02/12 12:47:16.470 PM com.apple.devicemanager:           from /usr/share/devicemgr/backend/devicemgrd:131
23/02/12 12:47:16.470 PM com.apple.launchd: (com.apple.devicemanager[1114]) Exited with code: 1
23/02/12 12:47:16.470 PM com.apple.launchd: (com.apple.devicemanager) Throttling respawn: Will start in 8 seconds
23/02/12 12:47:17.682 PM org.postgresql.postgres: postgres_real cannot access the server configuration file "/var/pgsql/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory
23/02/12 12:47:17.682 PM com.apple.launchd: (org.postgresql.postgres[1117]) Exited with code: 2
23/02/12 12:47:17.682 PM com.apple.launchd: (org.postgresql.postgres) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
23/02/12 12:47:24.482 PM com.apple.devicemanager: DEBUG: Initializing DeviceManagerDaemon with ports 3320,3321,3322,3323 (physmem = 4GB)
23/02/12 12:47:24.483 PM com.apple.devicemanager: DEBUG: Making sure Rails is configured properly
23/02/12 12:47:24.483 PM com.apple.devicemanager: DEBUG: Running rake command: /usr/bin/rake db:migrate
23/02/12 12:47:25.718 PM ruby: Unable to create ProfileManager log file at '/var/log/devicemgr/profilemanager.log' (No such file or directory)
23/02/12 12:47:25.718 PM ProfileManager: Unable to create ProfileManager log file at '/var/log/devicemgr/profilemanager.log' (No such file or directory)
23/02/12 12:47:25.718 PM com.apple.devicemanager: Feb 23 12:47:25 Computer.local ProfileManager[1121] <Error>: Unable to create ProfileManager log file at '/var/log/devicemgr/profilemanager.log' (No such file or directory)
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you got Lion Server installed and running? If so, you might fire up the server app or server manager app and see if there is a higher level issue.  You can use `serveradmin status devicemgr` as well to check on things.

Answer (score 2):

OS X Server update 3.0.1 seems to have cleared this up for me.

[Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-x-server/id714547929?mt=12)

[image: OS X Server Update]

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is to do this:

`sudo launchctl unload -w com.apple.devicemanager`

in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons`

WARNING this will kill profile manager,  but those services are mostly a waste of time anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But unfortunately Terminal reported "no such file or direction nothing found to unload"

Comment: "waste of time" might be a bit strong anyway. If they are not used they don't need significant ressources anyway, so just let them run.